# How to see whether db was hit or not when I run query in my app

Tags: mysql

Sorry if the question is stupid, but I have some strange behaviour in my app, and I want to see what is queried in mysql db in real time. Is that possible? Or not in real time, some logs with time with seconds will work as well.
Thanks a lot beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realtime -- I don't think so.

Log -- Turn on the "general log".  (The specifics depend on the version of MySQL you are running.)  That will write all queries to a file or table for later inspection.  Be sure to turn off the General log after you are finished; it could fill up disk rather fast.

Comment: in 5.6 if performance_schema is ON, one can enable events_statements_history and events_statements_history_long but i'm not sure if this is what he is looking for

Comment: The general log is a different thing.

Comment: You can have comments in your dml queries and thay will show up in binlogs.